# Moving files in java

Tags: java, swing, file, joptionpane, jfilechooser

So far this is my code i would like to move the selected file to a path that i will define later in the code how do i get the path from the selcted file

```
import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;



public class CopyFileExample 
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
        Component aComponent = null;
        int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(aComponent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the selected file this way:

```
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file = fc.getSelectedFile();
  ...
} else {
  // this means that the user closed the dialog or pressed Cancel
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most swing components have really good tutorials on the official site. The tutorial for `JFileChooser` is [here](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/filechooser.html).

It basically boils down to;

```
if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
  File file = fc.getSelectedFile().getPath();
  .....
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answers but how do i move the file from location a to location b (a will be ~/Downloads/FILE and b will be ~/Library/Application Support\ Minecraft/bin/minecraft.jar